# Running a formula for a list of entered criteria without having to enter one by one – would I need a macro for this?

Tags: excel, vba

I developed a spreadsheet that, when the user enters a search criteria (usually a person’s name), generates a well-written coherent sentence from a database of examination notes.  Basically, if you enter the name Fred into cell A1, then cell A2 returns the sentence “Fred took the level 5 maths exam on 15th March and scored 89%”.

I’m fairly happy with this so far. However, say I have a list of 100 names in column A on sheet 2 that I wanted to generate sentences for: currently, I enter the names one by one into cell A1, and copy and paste the generated sentences into a separate document.

Is there an easier way to do this? Ideally, for each name in column A on sheet 2, the corresponding generated sentence would be entered automatically next to it in column B, then the spreadsheet would carry on to the next name.

Would I need a macro to do this, or could I do this with a formula? At the moment, I just want to know where to start as I can’t see the wood for the trees.

I hope I’ve explained this clearly. Please let me know if I can clarify in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use cell **A2** to hold the sentence formula, use the *adjacent* cell **B1**

That way you can fill column **A** with the names list and just copy cell **B1** downwards!

**EDIT#1:**

Here is a macro-based solution.  Assumes that in Sheet1 **A1** contains a name and **A2** contains the big formula.  Assumes that in Sheet2 column **A** contains the name list and column **B** will receive the sentences.  Put the following in a standard module:

```
Sub SentenceMaker()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        s1.Range("A1").Value = s2.Cells(i, 1).Value
        DoEvents
        s2.Cells(i, 2).Value = s1.Range("A2").Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thank you for your response - unfortunately, the formula that generates is very complicated and jumps across a number of pages. If I was going to replicate it for each criteria, I would have to have about 4 or 5 sheets for each name! 

I was wondering if there was a way to automate excel to just enter the first name, collect the result, then move on to the next name? I've never used an excel macro before, but I have a suspicion this might be the answer. Just need someone with some experience on this!